# Eigenvalues' signs of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that seems intuitively simple but I am not able to prove. Consider two real square matrices $A$ and $B$. Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite and let $B$ be invertible and symmetric as well (I'm not sure if being symmetric is important).

I want to say that the eigenvalues of $B$ and the ones of the product $C = AB$ have the same signs. More formally, if $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ and $\mu_i$ are the eigenvalues of $C$, then:
$$
\mathrm{sign}(\lambda_i) = \mathrm{sign}(\mu_i),
$$
where $\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq\lambda_n$ and $\mu_1\leq\dots\leq\mu_n$.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!